# my custom class doesn't want to go into a container

Tags: mfc, c++-cli, containers

i have my class Personne.

```
#pragma once
#include <afxwin.h>         // MFC core and standard components
#include <afxext.h>         // MFC extensions
using namespace std;
using namespace System;

public ref class Personne
{
private:
    String ^_login;
    String ^_pwd;
    int _age;
public:
    Personne() {}
    Personne(String ^login, String ^pwd, int age) : _login(login), _pwd(pwd), _age(age) {}

    property String ^Login
    {
        String ^ get() { return _login; }
        void set(String ^value) { _login = value; }
    }

    property String ^Pwd
    {
        String^ get() { return _pwd; }
        void set(String ^value) { _pwd = value; }
    }
    property int Age
    {
        int get() { return _age; }
        void set(int value) { _age = value; }
    }
};
```

when i try to put it in any type of container i get a 30 or so errors all like this :
'*' : impossible to use this indirection on the type 'Personne'
'&' : impossible to use this indirection on the type 'Personne'

this all happens when i declare a container, like this

```
vector<Personne> mesPersonnes;
```

would anyone have any idee why this happens and how to resolve it?

Comment: `String^`  -- `public ref class` -- This stuff is not C++.

Comment: C++ containers are not really built to work with CLI classes...

Comment: i see. i have been a C# and java coder sins the beginning and am just now learning C++.

Comment: so CLI is not C++ ?

Comment: @lolplayer101 It isn't C++.  If it were, I would be able to take your code and compile it using the latest C++ compiler.  I can't because that is not C++ syntax that I mentioned.  There is no such thing as using the `^` operator in that context, and there is no such thing as `public ref class`.  So sticking something non-C++ in an STL C++ container is more than likely going to cause issues.

Comment: ok. in that case i have to reinvent my program from the start...
thanks for the clartification. i'll add my own answer saying explaining that.
sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Note that you're basically using .NET.  Doesn't .NET have container or collection classes? (I leave it to you to do the research).

Comment: the whole issue is that the program HAS to be Native C++

for later integration into another C++ program

Comment: C++/CLI **won't** compile to native code. The `public ref class Personne` compiles to MSIL, and requires the CLR to run. While there are hosting interfaces for the CLR, integrating it into a native C++ applications is a lot of work. Why are you writing .NET code, when your ultimate goal is to have an unmanaged C++ program? What's the rationale for that? What are you really trying to solve?

Comment: im new to C++ and some tutorials had this type of code so i emidiatly associated it to C++. nobody ever told me it was .NET ever. basically i used it because of a libary function it has. the XmlSerializer. i am looking to Serialize C++ objects into an xml file.

Comment: There is no XML support in Standard C++, so you are forced to use some library. If C++/CX is an option, this could be [Windows.Data.Xml.Dom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.data.xml.dom.aspx), or [MSXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742.aspx) for pure C or C++ code. Both require that you are familiar with COM, in exchange for not adding any external dependencies.

Comment: thanks you very much. the help is much appreciated. i will look into those libraries. but i will look into COM before that as that doesn't ring a bell either.

Comment: This is C++/CLI, which is a superset of C++03 designed to write glue code between .NET and C or C++. It doesn't make sense to use it for anything else than this purpose. If you want standard C++, don't use the `/cli` compiler option, and that syntax will become illegal.

Comment: i did not specifie that. i simply created an empty project and went coding using Commen Language Runtime (/clr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as a beginner C++ programmer i did not notice that this is a CLI class. which are not compatible with native C++.

there for not compatible with the native C++ containers.